How to share Updates
I have created a Python application with Selenium which I have converted into a one-file .exe using PyInstaller and shared it!
I want to add some nbew features, but these won't be visible to the users who already have the application. What should I do to provide updates to the users? How should I modify the code to be able to have updates?
Thank you
I attempted the following code (you can find the code below) with the help of ChatGPT, but all it does is simply download the .py files to the directory where the app is located! What I wanted is the following:
For example, if the original program was just to execute
print("Hello World") >>> Hello World
I want to change it with the update to print
print("Hello New World") >>> Hello New World
My Try:
import requests
import os
import sys
import zipfile
import tempfile
import shutil


def check_for_updates(current_version, repo_owner, repo_name):
    releases_url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/releases/latest"
    print(releases_url)
    try:
        response = requests.get(releases_url)
        release_info = response.json()
        latest_version = release_info["tag_name"]
        return latest_version
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error checking for updates: {e}")
        return None

def is_update_available(current_version, latest_version):
    return current_version < latest_version

def download_update(repo_owner, repo_name):
    releases_url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/releases/latest"
    try:
        response = requests.get(releases_url)
        release_info = response.json()
        assets = release_info["assets"]

        # Assuming the first asset is a zip file
        update_url = assets[0]["browser_download_url"]
        print(update_url)
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
            zip_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, "file1.zip")
            with open(zip_path, "wb") as zip_file:
                zip_file.write(requests.get(update_url).content)

            extract_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, "extracted_update")
            print("Extract Path: ", extract_path)
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, "r") as zip_ref:
                zip_ref.extractall(extract_path)

            # Replace old files with the updated ones
            update_files(extract_path)
            

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error downloading update: {e}")


def update_files(extract_path):
    # Replace old files with the updated ones
    app_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
    print(app_dir)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(extract_path):
        for file in files:
            src_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            relative_path = os.path.relpath(src_path, extract_path)
            dest_path = os.path.join(app_dir, relative_path)

            # Ensure the destination directory exists
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest_path), exist_ok=True)

            # Copy the file to the destination
            shutil.copy2(src_path, dest_path)

def main():
    
    current_version = "v0.1.0"
    latest_version = check_for_updates(current_version, "******************", "Updating")

    if latest_version and is_update_available(current_version, latest_version):
        print("Update available. Downloading...")
        download_update("******************", "Updating")
        print("Update complete. Please restart the application.")
    else:
        print("Your application is up to date.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Does this help?
snippet:
def main():
    
    current_version = "v0.1.0"
    latest_version = check_for_updates(current_version, "******************", "Updating")

    if latest_version and is_update_available(current_version, latest_version):
        data = "Update available. Downloading..." 
        download_update("******************", "Updating" 
        data = "Update complete. Please restart the application." 
    else:
        data = "Your application is up to date." 
    print(data) 


Hello, in the snippet you post changed the print statement and you assigned the values to the data variable!

Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.
